# emscripten_run_script() removed in optimised build

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

In my `.cpp` file I have a line:

```
emscripten_run_script("callOut();console.error('Hello');");
```

This function `callOut` just writes a message to the console so that I know it has been called.

This all works fine when building with `-g4`, but doesn't do anything when compiled with the recommended for release `-O2`. I can't even find the text "hello" in the javascript output.

Is it supposed to work like this?  Is there any way I can get this call in the release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't waiting for the emscripten code to be fully initialized before calling in to it.  You should wait until the emscripten `main()` function gets called, then you know it is ready.

The problem is made worse when using `-O2` as emcc creates a separate memory initialization file that must be loaded before the is emscripten code is ready.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to emscripten_run_script is to use the [EM_ASM](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.EM_ASM) macros. I've never had trouble with these disappearing in optimized builds.

So your example would be equivalent to

```
EM_ASM({
  callOut();
  console.error("Hello");
});
```